# Gravitation - why is it so confusing?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

First, does gravity emit from all directions around a star or planet equally.  Secondly, how is it that gravity pulls a planet closer, then it goes further out, without the planet changing orbit permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question: Yes gravity is mediated in all directions equally.

As for your second question: I assume you are asking about [elliptic orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit). If this is the case then, from the law of conservation of angular momentum, when the planet is closer to the sun it has greater velocity, and when its further out it travels slower because

$\vec{L}$ = $\vec{r}$ x $\vec{p}$

You can see now that lower radius orbits are required to have more momentum, and consequently velocity, to keep angular momentum conserved.

Comment: Could you comment on how Lagrange points are related to this? I would appreciate it.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxpVbU5FH0s) is a great video on Lagrange points by Sixty Symbols

Comment: That was a great video, it makes more sense now.

Comment: Hell, thats just basic geometry.  I'm old.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. Some of these stuff can be quite confusing sometimes.

Comment: @Jody, it's all confusing until it isn't.  Sometimes, it's just one little notion that needs to be adjusted and then the dots just connect themselves.